# Multiple buttons for one action without IB

Tags: swift, uibutton, action

In my view controller, I have 10 buttons. Each button has a tag and all the buttons call the same action (separate by a switch (sender.tag), case 0 -> case 9 to differentiate which button is selected). 
I made with IB, connected all the buttons (`@IBOutlet`) to the same `@IBAction` and everything is good. But now I want to do this programmatically, without IB.

So I removed the `@IBOutlet`'s and the `@IBAction` to create new buttons (`let myButton1 = UIBUtton()`) and a new action (`func newAction(sender: UIButton)`). I tried an `addTarget:` with the same selector for all the new buttons, but the app crashes.

Anyone has an idea to fix it please ?

Comment: `target` should be `self` and `action` should be `"newAction:"`.  Note the colon.

Comment: Everything is good like this, thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
func newAction(sender: UIButton) {
    ...
}
...
myButton1.addTarget(self, action: "newAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
myButton2.addTarget(self, action: "newAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
myButton3.addTarget(self, action: "newAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: It works, indeed ! Thank you for your quick answer !

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. I have two buttons, one on the left and one on the right. I set the tag value to `0` on the left one and `1` on the right one. The `enum` is all the tags, so you could have as many buttons as you want. Make sure to link the buttons to the same `IBAction` from storyboard.

```
class QuestionViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var leftButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIButton!

    enum ButtonType: Int { case Left = 0, Right }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func questionAnswered(sender: UIButton) {
        switch(ButtonType(rawValue: sender.tag)!){
        case .Left:
            leftButton.setTitle("left button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        case .Right:
            rightButton.setTitle("right button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }

    }
}
```